# Order of memory locations

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

What is the order of memory locations allocated by new operator?

For the context, if we are implementing a linked list, then does the new nodes created successively have increasing memory locations?

Comment: Unspecified. Maybe, maybe not. Why do you need to know?

Comment: *if we are implementing a linked list, then does the new nodes created successively have increasing memory locations?*  **No.**  They may be happenstance increasing memory locations, but that could not be relied upon from run-to-run.  And on some architectures (e.g., DS9K) may not even be a sensible question to ask.

Comment: You may observe it in limited testing of an implementation however there is no guarantee of this and you should not trust it anyways.

Comment: Are we even guaranteed that the memory locations of the nodes of a linked list are sortable? I think only pointers within a single array can be reliably compared in such a way. (unless we specify an implementation, of course)

Comment: Just now, I solved a linked list cycle detection problem assuming that successive nodes will have memory locations in increasing order, so problem boils down to whether there is a decrease in node locations. And it worked. Curious whether new allocated memory in that way. @n. 1.

Comment: You cannot depend on successive increasing memory addresses for that. I believe the tortoise/hare algorithm is the canonical naive way to detect cycles

Comment: @JohnFilleau since you asked, such pointers are not sortable with `<`, but they are sortable with `std::less`.  This is how `std::set<T*>` operates.

Comment: @DrewDormann I appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the order of memory locations allocated by new operator?

The order is unspecified by the language. The order is what-ever the language implementation chooses it to be.

> if we are implementing a linked list, then does the new nodes created successively have increasing memory locations?

If you use the default allocator, then they could have; but they might not have. And if they do have, that may be incidental. There are no guarantees either way.

If you write an allocator of your own, then you are in control of the allocations.